# Reading file using fscanf is not working in c?

Tags: c, pointers

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    char *input = "input.txt";
    int *account;
    char **name;
    float *balance;
    int count;
    int check;

    if (argc < 4 || argc > 4) {
        printf("Insufficient arguments. Check your command line arguments\n");
        return 1;
    }
    count = atoi(*(argv + 2));
    name = malloc(sizeof(char) * 20 * count);
    account = malloc(sizeof(int) * count);
    balance = malloc(sizeof(float) * count);

    check = load_data(input, name, account, balance, count);
    if (check == 0) {
        printf("File cannot be open\n");
    }

    print_data(name, account, balance, count);

    free(name);
    return 0;
} 

//load data from input file the according arrays
int load_data(char *input, char **name, int *acct, float *amt, int n) {
    int *a = acct;
    float *b = amt;
    FILE *file = fopen("input.txt", "r");
    int i;

    if (file == NULL) {
        return 0;
    } else {
        for (i = 0; i < 9; i++, acct++, amt++) {
            fscanf(file, "%s %d %f", *(name + i), acct, amt);
        }
    }
    fclose(file);
    acct = a; //return pointer to original position
    amt = b;
    return 1;
}

//print data from arrays
void print_data(char **name, int *acct, float *amt, int n) {
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        printf("%-10s%-13s%s\n", "Name", "Account No.", "Amount");
        printf("%-10s%-13d%7.2f\n", *(name + i), *(acct + i), *(amt + i));
    }
}
```

I have this `load_data` function that suppose to read from a file and store the data values in different pointers, but for some reason when I print out using `print_data` function, the pointer contain all null and 0? (Please answer using pointers arithmetic and not array)

Comment: This is not enough to answer. Are input, name, acct, amt initialized? Did you check if malloc return NULL or not? I see you don't check how many characters fscanf reads... Post also your code which initializes all your arguments

Comment: Did you allocate memory for all those values?  Show us how you call `load_data`.

Comment: OT: `acct = a;` and `amt = b;` are useless, as the functions is left anyway, and their values are lost. They are just copies of the values pass to the functions.

Comment: OT^2 : All those `i`s and `n`s should be `size_t` not `int`.

Comment: OT^3: Doing `name[i]` instead of  `*(name+i)` is more common, more clear, less misunderstandable, error-prone.

Comment: This is an assignment in class to practice pointer so i can't use any [ ] bracket

Comment: `name[i] = NULL;` is just the same as `*(name+i) = NULL;` it can be useful to know that when thinking about pointer arithmetic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I expect that you have not properly prepared the arrays before calling the function... the below main function will work with your code:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    int n = 10;
    char ** name = malloc(n * sizeof(char*));
    int* acct = malloc(n * sizeof(int));
    float* amt = malloc(n * sizeof(float));
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        // this is allocating some space for each line
        // this is quite bad you should range check.
        name[i] = malloc(256);
    }
    load_data("", name, acct, amt, n);
    print_data(name, acct, amt, n);
    // TODO: free everything
}
```

in `load_data`: `a` and `b` are not required and as `amt` and `acct` are "passed by value" there is no need to restore their values at the end of your function. That is to say that the values in all your arguments will be discarded when this function returns only the values that are "pointed to" are updated.

Example input.txt file:

```
Adam 1 900.9
Daniel 2  800.8
Joe 3       700.7
Foo 4 600.6
Bar 5 500.5
Alice 6 400.4
Bob 7 300.3
Nick 8 200.2
Eve 9 100.1
```

After altering your code slightly (see below) the above input file does work, here is the output I get:

```
$ ./test 5 5 5
Name      Account No.  Amount
Adam      1             900.90
Name      Account No.  Amount
Daniel    2             800.80
Name      Account No.  Amount
Joe       3             700.70
Name      Account No.  Amount
Foo       4             600.60
Name      Account No.  Amount
Bar       5             500.50
```

Updated main function based on the one you provided in the question:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    char *input = "input.txt";
    int *account;
    char **name;
    float *balance;
    int count;
    int check;
    int i;

    if (argc < 4 || argc > 4) {
        printf("Insufficient arguments. Check your command line arguments\n");
        return 1;
    }
    count = atoi(*(argv + 2));
    name = malloc(sizeof(char *) * count);
    for (i = 0; i < count; i ++) {
        *(name+i) = malloc(20);
    }
    account = malloc(sizeof(int) * count);
    balance = malloc(sizeof(float) * count);

    check = load_data(input, name, account, balance, count);
    if (check == 0) {
        printf("File cannot be open\n");
    }

    print_data(name, account, balance, count);

    free(balance);
    free(account);
    for (i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        free(*(name+i));
    }
    free(name);
    return 0;
}
```

... also in `load_data` I changed `i < 9` to `i < n`.

Comment: What do the pointers in your `char **name` array of character pointers point to?

Comment: In this example char **name is a pointer to more pointers. If you look later you will see that the name array is being filled with n pointers to n blocks of memory (allocated by malloc) for use in the load_data function.

Comment: I added my main function

Comment: Hello Gtt123, as I said your problem is that you have not correctly initialised the name character pointer array. name is a pointer to a block of memory that contains pointers. `name = malloc(10*sizeof(char*));` is the pointer to your pointers then you can allocate separate space for each element... `*(name+0) = malloc(128);` or `name[0] = malloc(128);` allocates 128 bytes to the first element. Otherwise you should skip a set number of bytes each time around the loop `char *name; name=malloc(10*128*sizeof(char)); for (int i=0;i<10;i++){sscanf(file,"%s",name);name=name+(128);}`